# Faster Way to Import Excel Spreadsheet to Array With ADO

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2007, ado

I am trying to import and sort data from a large excel report into a new file using Excel 2007 VBA. I have come up with two methods so far for doing this:

1. Have Excel actually open the file (code below), gather all data into arrays and output the arrays onto new sheets in the same file and save/close it.

   ```
    Public Sub GetData()

        Dim FilePath As String

        FilePath = "D:\File_Test.xlsx"
        Workbooks.OpenText Filename:=FilePath, FieldInfo:=Array(Array(2, 2))
        ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1).Select

    End Sub
   ```
2. Use ADO to get all data out of the closed workbook, import the whole datasheet into an array (code below) and sort data from there and then output data into a new workbook and save/close that.

   ```
    Private Sub PopArray() 'Uses ADO to populate an array that will be used to sort data
        Dim dbConnection As ADODB.Connection, rs As ADODB.Recordset
        Dim Getvalue, SourceRange, SourceFile, dbConnectionString  As String

        SourceFile = "D:\File_Test.xlsx"
        SourceRange = "B1:Z180000"

        dbConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
        "Data Source=" & SourceFile & ";" & _
        "Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=No"";"
        Set dbConnection = New ADODB.Connection
        dbConnection.Open dbConnectionString 'open the database connection

        Set rs = dbConnection.Execute("SELECT * FROM [" & SourceRange & "]")
        Arr = rs.GetRows

        UpBound = UBound(Arr, 2)
        rs.Close
    End Sub
   ```

The test file used has about 65000 records to sort through (about a third of what I will end up using it for). I was kind of disappointed when the ADO version only performed marginally better than the open worksheet (~44 seconds vs ~40 seconds run time). I was wondering if there is some way to improve the ADO import method (or a completely different method - ExecuteExcel4Macro maybe? - if there is one) that would boost my speed. The only thing I could think of was that I am using `"B1:Z180000"` as my `SourceRange` as a maximum range that is then truncated by setting `Arr = rs.GetRows` to accurately reflect the total number of records. If that is what is causing the slow down, I'm not sure how I would go about finding how many rows are in the sheet.

Edit - I am using Range("A1:A" & i) = (Array) to insert data into the new worksheet.

Comment: You can speed this up greatly by using the `Sheet.UsedRange` property and `.CopyFromRecordset` instead of looping through an array.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7091653/using-adodb-in-vbscript-to-find-the-number-of-rows-in-an-excel-sheet

Comment: It would help to see your method of actually populating the data into the new workbook, but I believe @jbarkee2160 may be right.

Comment: The biggest chunk of time is taken up by opening the ADODB connection (~26s), the next longest time is sorting out the data in arrays and inserting it into a sheet via `Range("A1:A" & i) = (Array)` which takes ~7s. Inserting the data into an array takes ~5s. @jbarkee2160, the `.CopyFromRecordset` method looks like it would help if all I wanted to do was copy data to a sheet, but I need to split it up and weed out unneeded data first which I believe would be better to do in arrays instead of on the sheet. I'm also not seeing a way to use `Sheet.UsedRange` on a closed workbook...

Comment: @110SidedHexagon, it sounds like an answer ;)

Answer (score 0):

This answer might not be what you are looking for but I still felt compelled to post it based on your side note [...] or a completely different method ]...].

Here, I am working with files of 200MB (and more) each which are merely text files including delimiters. I do not load them into Excel anymore. I also had the problem that Excel was too slow and needs to load the entire file. Yet, Excel is very fast at opening these files using the `Open` method:

```
Open strFileNameAndPath For Input Access Read Lock Read As #intPointer
```

In this case Excel is not loading the entire file but merely reading it line by line. So, Excel can already process the data (forward it) and then grab the next line of data. Like this Excel does not neet the memory to load 200MB.

With this method I am then loading the data in a locally installed SQL which transfers the data directly to our DWH (also SQL). To speed up the transfer using the above mething and getting the data fast into the SQL server I am transferring the data in chunks of 1000 rows each. The string variable in Excel can hold up to 2 billion characters. So, there is not problem there.

One might wonder why I am not simply using SSIS if I am already using a local installation of SQL. Yet, the problem is that I am not the one loading all these files anymore. Using Excel to generate this "import tool" allowed me to forward these tools to others, who are now uploading all these files for me. Giving all of them access to SSIS was not an option nor the possibility of using a destined network drive where one could place these files and SSIS would automatically load them (ever 10+ minutes or so).

In the end my code looks something like this.

```
Set conRCServer = New ADODB.Connection
conRCServer.ConnectionString = "PROVIDER=SQLOLEDB; " _
    & "DATA SOURCE=" & Ref.Range("C2").Value2 & ";" _
    & "INITIAL CATALOG=" & Ref.Range("C4").Value & ";" _
    & "Integrated Security=SSPI "
On Error GoTo SQL_ConnectionError
conRCServer.Open
On Error GoTo 0

'Save the name of the current file
strCurrentFile = ActiveWorkbook.Name

'Prepare a dialog box for the user to pick a file and show it
'   ...if no file has been selected then exit
'   ...otherwise parse the selection into it's path and the name of the file
Call Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen).Filters.Clear
Call Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen).Filters.Add("Extracts", "*.csv")
Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen).Title = "Select ONE Extract to import..."
Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen).AllowMultiSelect = False
intChoice = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen).Show
If intChoice <> 0 Then
    strFileToPatch = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen).SelectedItems(1)
Else
    Exit Sub
End If

'Open the Extract for import and close it afterwards
intPointer = FreeFile()
Open strFileNameAndPath For Input Access Read Lock Read As #intPointer

intCounter = 0
strSQL = vbNullString
Do Until EOF(intPointer)
    Line Input #intPointer, strLine
    If Left(strLine, 4) = """@@@" Then Exit Sub
    '*********************************************************************
    '** Starting a new SQL command
    '*********************************************************************
    If intCounter = 0 Then
        Set rstResult = New ADODB.Recordset
        strSQL = "set nocount on; "
        strSQL = strSQL & "insert into dbo.tblTMP "
        strSQL = strSQL & "values "
    End If
    '*********************************************************************
    '** Transcribe the current line into SQL
    '*********************************************************************
    varArray = Split(strLine, ",")
    strSQL = strSQL & " (" & varArray(0) & ", " & varArray(1) & ", N'" & varArray(2) & "', "
    strSQL = strSQL & " N'" & varArray(3) & "', N'" & varArray(4) & "', N'" & varArray(5) & "', "
    strSQL = strSQL & " N'" & varArray(6) & "', " & varArray(8) & ", N'" & varArray(9) & "', "
    strSQL = strSQL & " N'" & varArray(10) & "', N'" & varArray(11) & "', N'" & varArray(12) & "', "
    strSQL = strSQL & " N'" & varArray(13) & "', N'" & varArray(14) & "', N'" & varArray(15) & "' ), "
    '*********************************************************************
    '** Execute the SQL command in bulks of 1.000
    '*********************************************************************
    If intCounter >= 1000 Then
        strSQL = Mid(strSQL, 1, Len(strSQL) - 2)
        rstResult.ActiveConnection = conRCServer
        On Error GoTo SQL_StatementError
        rstResult.Open strSQL
        On Error GoTo 0
        If Not rstResult.EOF And Not rstResult.BOF Then
            strErrorMessage = "The server returned the following error message(s):" & Chr(10)
            While Not rstResult.EOF And Not rstResult.BOF
                strErrorMessage = Chr(10) & strErrorMessage & rstResult.Fields(0).Value
                rstResult.MoveNext
            Wend
            MsgBox strErrorMessage & Chr(10) & Chr(10) & "Aborting..."
            Exit Sub
        End If
    End If
    intCounter = intCounter + 1
Loop

Close intPointer

Set rstResult = Nothing

Exit Sub

SQL_ConnectionError:
Y = MsgBox("Couldn't connect to the server. Please make sure that you have a working internet connection. " & _
            "Do you want me to prepare an error-email?", 52, "Problems connecting to Server...")
If Y = 6 Then
    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)
    With OutMail
        .To = Ref.Range("C7").Value2
        .CC = Ref.Range("C8").Value2
        .Subject = "Problems connecting to database '" & Ref.Range("C4").Value & "' on server '" & Ref.Range("C2").Value & "'"
        .HTMLBody = "<span style=""font-size:10px"">---Automatically generated Error-Email---" & _
                "</span><br><br>Error report from the file '" & _
                "<span style=""color:blue"">" & ActiveWorkbook.Name & _
                "</span>' located and saved on '<span style=""color:blue"">" & _
                ActiveWorkbook.Path & "</span>'.<br>" & _
                "Excel is not able to establish a connection to the server. Technical data to follow." & "<br><br>" & _
                "Computer Name:    <span style=""color:green;"">" & Environ("COMPUTERNAME") & "</span><br>" & _
                "Logged in as:     <span style=""color:green;"">" & Environ("USERDOMAIN") & "/" & Environ("USERNAME") & "</span><br>" & _
                "Domain Server:    <span style=""color:green;"">" & Environ("LOGONSERVER") & "</span><br>" & _
                "User DNS Domain:  <span style=""color:green;"">" & Environ("USERDNSDOMAIN") & "</span><br>" & _
                "Operating System: <span style=""color:green;"">" & Environ("OS") & "</span><br>" & _
                "Excel Version:    <span style=""color:green;"">" & Application.Version & "</span><br>" & _
                "<br><span style=""font-size:10px""><br>" & _
                "<br><br>---Automatically generated Error-Email---"
        .Display
    End With
    Set OutMail = Nothing
    Set OutApp = Nothing
End If
Exit Sub

SQL_StatementError:
Y = MsgBox("There seems to be a problem with the SQL Syntax in the programming. " & _
            "May I send an error-email to development team?", 52, "Problems with the coding...")
If Y = 6 Then
    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)
    With OutMail
        .To = Ref.Range("C8").Value2
        '.CC = ""
        .Subject = "Problems with the SQL Syntax in file '" & ActiveWorkbook.Name & "'."
        .HTMLBody = "<span style=""font-size:10px"">" & _
                "---Automatically generated Error-Email---" & _
                "</span><br><br>" & _
                "Error report from the file '" & _
                "<span style=""color:blue"">" & _
                ActiveWorkbook.Name & _
                "</span>" & _
                "' located and saved on '" & _
                "<span style=""color:blue"">" & _
                ActiveWorkbook.Path & _
                "</span>" & _
                "'.<br>" & _
                "It seems that there is a problem with the SQL-Code within trying to upload an extract to the server." & _
                "SQL-Code causing the problems:" & _
                "<br><br><span style=""color:green;"">" & _
                strSQL & _
                "</span><br><br><span style=""font-size:10px"">" & _
                "---Automatically generated Error-Email---"
        .Display
    End With
    Set OutMail = Nothing
    Set OutApp = Nothing
End If
Exit Sub

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

i think that @Mr. Mascaro is right the easiest way to past your data from a `Recordset` into a spreadsheet is:

```
Private Sub PopArray()
    .....
    Set rs = dbConnection.Execute("SELECT * FROM [" & SourceRange & "]")  
    '' This is faster
    Range("A1").CopyFromRecordset rs
    ''Arr = rs.GetRows
End Sub
```

but if you still want to use `Arrays` you could try this:

```
Sub ArrayTest  

'' Array for Test
Dim aSingleArray As Variant  
Dim aMultiArray as Variant  

'' Set values 
aSingleArray = Array("A","B","C","D","E")  
aMultiArray = Array(aSingleArray, aSingleArray)

'' You can drop data from the Array using 'Resize'
'' Btw, your Array must be transpose to use this :P
Range("A1").Resize( _
            UBound(aMultiArray(0), 1) + 1, _  
            UBound(aMultiArray, 1) + 1) = Application.Transpose(aMultiArray)

End Sub
```