# How to remove missing references via script in Excel VBA?

Tags: vba, excel

I have excel that is use by many users. Some of them do not have installed all software's and therefore missing references. I am, trying to have script that remove all references that can not be found on C: drive.

I have this code in /Microsoft Excel Objects / ThisWorkbook
but is not fully working. Anyone could help me with this.

```
Sub TestRef()
Dim REF As VBIDE.Reference
Dim WB As Workbook
Set WB = ThisWorkbook
For Each REF In WB.VBProject.References
    If StrComp(Left(REF.FullPath, 1), "C", vbTextCompare) <> 0 Then
        DelRef
        Debug.Print REF.Name, REF.Description, REF.FullPath
    End If
Next REF
End Sub

Sub DelRef()
Dim REF As VBIDE.Reference
Dim WB As Workbook
Set WB = ThisWorkbook
With ThisWorkbook.VBProject.References
    .Remove .Item("MSForms")
End With    
End Sub
```

[Missing Referece Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/siJ1B.png)

Comment: Just out of curiosity: when you are removing the missing references. Doesn't this also mean that the code in the file won't work and shouldn't run? Are you (hence) also removing the underlying code? How about writing an automated email to the system administrator when a broken reference is found (instead of removing it)? Then the system admin can install the missing software. At the bottom of the following solution you'll find a short snippet to automatically generate an Outlook email (in which you could request installation of the missing software): http://stackoverflow.com/a/30346959/1153513

Comment: this is good idea as well I will try to add this as well. Some people run codes that link to external software but all people must be able to open and see current status and run normal excel operation. There are dedicated Click to link with external tools.

Comment: Anyone any idea how to solve it.... so far no solution?

Answer (score 1):

Not with your variables names, but something I wrote a while back and I've been using for a while to remove "Missing" references :

```
Dim theRef As Variant, i As Long

' loop through all References in VB Project
For i = ThisWorkbook.VBProject.References.Count To 1 Step -1
    Set theRef = ThisWorkbook.VBProject.References.Item(i)

    ' if reference is "Missing" >> remove it to avoid error message
    If theRef.isbroken = True Then
        ThisWorkbook.VBProject.References.Remove theRef
    End If

    ' just for Debug
    ' Debug.Print theRef.Description & ";" & theRef.FullPath & ";" & theRef.isbroken & vbCr
Next i
```

Comment: thanks, when I run I have _itallic_ Run-time error '-2147319779' Method 'FullPath' of object 'Reference' failed

Comment: @Michal ok, and without the `Debug` line ? I've made it as a comment

Comment: Do you need to trust the `VBA Project Object Model` for this?

Comment: @Tom Yes (but there is a way to get around it, a very long code I've tested involving VBScript)

Comment: Would you care to share? Would be interested to see how you get round this

Comment: @Tom I will, I need to "clean" it up a little (it inside something related to work), and one I have I'll upload it to my **GitHub** rep, ok ? link to my profile https://github.com/shairad

Comment: @Michal is it working for you without the `Debug.Print` line ?

Comment: @ShaiRado Unfortunately not, I commented this line but now have Run-time error '-2147319779' Object library not registered

Comment: @ShaiRado I am using as `Private Sub Workbook_Open()` to make sure if run when opening file but it does not remove missing references

Comment: @Michal strange, I ran the code above with the `Debug.Print` line and it works fine

Comment: @Tom try the link to me rep. https://github.com/shairad/Excel-VBA-VBAProject-Model-

Comment: Thanks for this. so you're using a registry edit and restarting excel to enable it without the user enabling it?

Comment: @Tom yes, but it's automatic, and the user doesn't have to do anything. Once it's enabled, it's not restarted, it runs regularly

Comment: @ShaiRado hmm this is strange,

Comment: @Michal open a new workbook from scratch, just copy the code from my answer in the `Workbook_Open` event, and see if it runs ok

Comment: @ShaiRado, I checked and this does not work, please find attached file...I can not attach file...hmm I set up simple file for test but there is no way to share it....

Comment: @ShaiRado still  _Run-time error '-2147319779' Object library not registered_ this error in on this line `ThisWorkbook.VBProject.References.Remove theRef`

Answer (score 0):

Removing a missing reference will not solve the problem because the reference is needed for some propose or it wouldn't have been added in the first place.

Another way of dealing with missing reference: Closing the Excel file if it has a missing reference, then complete the Object library installation of the needed reference by Excel VBA in a different Excel file.

You may notify the user there is a missing part of the installation and suggest closing the file to complete the installation.

See: [Catch 22 -Installing reference library (Selenium) by Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69067614/catch-22-installing-reference-library-selenium-by-excel-vba)